# VS 2022 project is missing the x64 option, only has Any CPU as option

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2022

I am at my wits end. I have a VS 2022 VB Winforms application that was working perfectly fine up until last night. Now I am getting numerous errors, most of which state "Value of type 'ComboBox()' cannot be converted to 'ComboBox()' because 'ComboBox' is not derived from 'ComboBox'". Another error staes "'DropDownWidth' is not a member of 'ComboBox'". The only thing I noticed is that the solution platform now reads "Any CPU" instead of "x64". I did not change any code that has to do with the combobox routines so the errors seemed to have come out of nowhere and the x64 solution platform is no longer an option. Any ideas? I included my code where the errors started popping up.

```
Public Class GlobalVar
    Public Shared cmbBurgType() As ComboBox = {frmSearchNOC.cmbSearchBurgType, frmAddEntry.cmbAddBurgType}
    Public Shared cmbSex() As ComboBox = {frmSearchNOC.cmbSearchSex, frmAddEntry.cmbAddSex}
    Public Shared cmbRace() As ComboBox = {frmSearchNOC.cmbSearchRace, frmAddEntry.cmbAddRace}
    Public Shared cmbPrefix() As ComboBox = {frmSearchNOC.cmbSearchHomeStreetPrefix, frmAddEntry.cmbAddHAddressPrefix}
    Public Shared cmbSuffix() As ComboBox = {frmSearchNOC.cmbSearchHomeStreetSuffix, frmAddEntry.cmbAddHAddressSuffix}
    Public Shared cmbState() As ComboBox = {frmSearchNOC.cmbSearchHomeState, frmAddEntry.cmbAddHAddressState}
    Public Shared cmbPrecinct() As ComboBox = {frmSearchNOC.cmbSearchHomePrecinct, frmAddEntry.cmbAddHAddressPrecinct}
    Public Shared cmbTattooLoc() As ComboBox = {frmSearchNOC.cmbSearchTattooLocation, frmAddEntry.cmbAddTattoo}
End Class




Public Sub LoadPresetDBDataCombobox(tableName As String, colName As String, objArray() As ComboBox)
        Dim longestEntry As String = ""
        Dim curText As String = ""

        Dim sqliteReader As SQLiteDataReader
        Dim sqliteReadCmd As SQLiteCommand

        'clear combobox items
        For Each curBox As ComboBox In objArray
            curBox.Items.Clear()
        Next

        OpenDBConn() 'opens the database connection

        sqliteReadCmd = GlobalVar.dbConn.CreateCommand()
        sqliteReadCmd.CommandText = "Select " & colName & " FROM " & tableName
        sqliteReader = sqliteReadCmd.ExecuteReader()
        sqliteReadCmd.Dispose() 'disposes read command after it is used

        'iterate through table
        Using sqliteReader
            While sqliteReader.Read
                curText = sqliteReader.GetString(colName) 'gets the current table value for the selcted column

                'places value into each combobox in array
                For Each curBox As ComboBox In objArray
                    curBox.Items.Add(curText)
                Next


                'determines the length of the longest string to size to properly dize the drop down width to fit text
                If (curText.Length > longestEntry.Length) Then
                    longestEntry = curText
                End If
            End While


            'assigns the dropdownwidth based on an everage character width of 6 pixels
            For Each curBox As ComboBox In objArray
                curBox.DropDownWidth = ((longestEntry.Length * 7) + 10)
            Next


            sqliteReader.Close() 'close object
            longestEntry = ""
        End Using

        CloseDBConn() 'closes the database connection
    End Sub




Private Sub OpenChildForm(childForm As Form, formIndex As Integer)
        If (currentChildForm IsNot Nothing) Then
            currentChildForm.SendToBack()
        End If


        currentChildForm = childForm 'assigns passed in form as current form
        childForm.TopLevel = False 'indicated the form is not top level because the main form is top level
        childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill 'docks form to fill main form's panel
        pnlMain.Controls.Add(childForm) 'adds form to the main panel on the main form
        pnlMain.Tag = childForm 'associate form to main panel on main form
        childForm.BringToFront() 'brings the related form to the front
        childForm.Show()

        Select Case formIndex
            Case 0 'search noc form
                'reloads various data from db into comboboxes in case items were added while on another tab
                LoadPresetDBDataCombobox("BurgType", "typeName", GlobalVar.cmbBurgType) 'tattoo location
                LoadPresetDBDataCombobox("Sex", "sexName", GlobalVar.cmbSex) 'sex
                LoadPresetDBDataCombobox("Race", "raceName", GlobalVar.cmbRace) 'race
                LoadPresetDBDataCombobox("StreetPrefix", "prefixName", GlobalVar.cmbPrefix) 'street prefix
                LoadPresetDBDataCombobox("StreetSuffix", "suffixName", GlobalVar.cmbSuffix) 'street suffix
                LoadPresetDBDataCombobox("State", "stateName", GlobalVar.cmbState) 'state
                LoadPresetDBDataCombobox("Precinct", "precinctName", GlobalVar.cmbPrecinct) 'home precinct
                LoadPresetDBDataCombobox("BodyPart", "bodyPartName", GlobalVar.cmbTattooLoc) 'tattoo location
            Case 1 'browse results form

            Case 2 'add entry form
                'reloads various data from db into comboboxes in case items were added while on another tab
                LoadPresetDBDataCombobox("BurgType", "typeName", GlobalVar.cmbBurgType) 'tattoo location
                LoadPresetDBDataCombobox("Sex", "sexName", GlobalVar.cmbSex) 'sex
                LoadPresetDBDataCombobox("Race", "raceName", GlobalVar.cmbRace) 'race
                LoadPresetDBDataCombobox("StreetPrefix", "prefixName", GlobalVar.cmbPrefix) 'street prefix
                LoadPresetDBDataCombobox("StreetSuffix", "suffixName", GlobalVar.cmbSuffix) 'street suffix
                LoadPresetDBDataCombobox("State", "stateName", GlobalVar.cmbState) 'state
                LoadPresetDBDataCombobox("Precinct", "precinctName", GlobalVar.cmbPrecinct) 'home precinct
                LoadPresetDBDataCombobox("BodyPart", "bodyPartName", GlobalVar.cmbTattooLoc) 'tattoo location
            Case 3'user settings form

            Case 4 'administrator form

        End Select
    End Sub
```

Above, the errors come into play with all the GlobalVar parameters as well as the dropdownwidth call:

```
LoadPresetDBDataCombobox("StreetPrefix", "prefixName", GlobalVar.cmbPrefix)
curBox.DropDownWidth = ((longestEntry.Length * 7) + 10)
```

I tried updating VS 2022 and then reinstalled it. Neither of which worked, obviously, considering I'm asking this question. It's probably something simple and stupid but I am fried and could use some help.

Comment: It sounds like you may have a name clash somewhere. If you navigate to the definition of `ComboBox` from that code, where does it take you?

Comment: It takes me to public class combobox in system.windows.forms

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to anyone who spent time reading my question. I have no idea how or when the following import got added to one of my routines but I commented it out and all the errors went away:

```
Imports System.Windows.Controls
```

I noticed it when I was copying code from my broken project to a new project to see when the errors start popping up. My best guess is that it was importing a combobox control that was different from the combobox I was trying to pass into the routine, but any comments that explain the reason are appreciated.